# Проблема с users.get. не могу достать last_name из полученного массива

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, бот

У меня не получается достать ни один ключ из этого списка.

```
[
  {
    id: *,
    first_name: '*',
    last_name: '*',
    can_access_closed: *,
    is_closed: *
  }
]
```

Мой код:

```
bot.command('/Команда', async (msg) => { 

let user = msg.message.from_id

let info = await bot.execute('users.get', { user_id: user })

let name = info.last_name

console.log(name) --> undefined
```

Я пробовал

`let info = await bot.execute('users.get', { user_id: user1 }).then(data => {console.log(data.last_name)}) --> undefined`

Comment: ты же знаешь что такое массивы?

Comment: Здравствуй, да, знаю.

Comment: Отлично. Значит знаешь как обращаться к каждому элементу.....теперь знакомьтесь, то что в вопросе - это массив

Comment: Я их путаю, но не в этом суть. Я понял как обратиться, info[0].last_name, тем временем я использовал info.last_name[0]

Comment: ну вот и всё) вопрос решён)

Answer (score 0):

`let info = await bot.execute('users.get', { user_id: user })`

```
[
  {
    id: *,
    first_name: '*',
    last_name: '*',
    can_access_closed: *,
    is_closed: *
  }
]
```

`info[0].last_name`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]